# How to create many ERC721 tokens sharing the same metadata tokenURI but different TokenId?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, ipfs, meta-data

I'm actually trying to create an NFT Marketplace, where a user can upload his NFT (create/mint new NFT) and other users can give some Ether and mint the same NFT. Trying to achieve this with the ERC721 standard. Maybe ERC1155 will be a better choice but I have to use ERC721.

So, I think how I can achieve this using ERC721 by minting NFTs with different tokenIDs but with pointing to the same NFT metadata or TokenURI.

I know this is possible as mentioned in this post: [Two ERC721 tokens that refer to the same metadata](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59765/two-erc721-tokens-that-refer-to-the-same-metadata)

But I can't fo it programatically.

This is how I'm trying: (It's not working, even 1 NFT is not showing on he opensea testnet)

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract navich is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {

    using Strings for uint256;
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenId;
    string public baseURI = "ipfs://QmRyezUtChrpvH4i4wKEoPngwTFKHuu4YYjZrSg89wvqVq/";

    constructor() ERC721("Wagmi", "Wagmi") {}

    function mintNFT() public payable {
        uint256 dynamic = 1;
        _tokenId.increment();
        _mint(msg.sender, _tokenId.current());
        _setTokenURI(dynamic, baseURI);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    baseURI,
                    tokenId.toString(),
                    ".json"
                )
            );
    }

    // function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    //     require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

    //     return "ipfs://QmRyezUtChrpvH4i4wKEoPngwTFKHuu4YYjZrSg89wvqVq";
    // }

}
```

Pls, Help me out. I need to get this thing done asap. and btw this is not the full Marketplace code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced this is the best answer, because I found this post looking for a better one. But it at least works:

```
    // set the base uri at top of contract
    string public uri = "ipfs://<enter your cid here>"
    
    function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        // _tokenId parameter required to override the base function
        // even though it's not used (same uri for all NFTs)

        return uri;
    }
```

What I don't like is the compiler complaining that I am not using the _tokenId variable. But if I remove it then it is not actually overriding the underlying tokenURI method so it has to stay.